# Finding text from webpage using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am tring to make a script but I can't really find a solution.

I'm trying to find a string from a website. Hard part here is that I can't use

```
document.documentElement.innerHTML.search("string")
```

Since I can't do it locally, I want to use something like this:

```
var link = "myweb.com"
link.documentElement.innerHTML.search("string")
```

At the moment, my script generates the link, opens it and closes it: I just need to search the webpage for the word "error."

Comment: Your code (in a browser) won't be able to look at contents of pages fetched from other domains; the browser won't allow it. You can do it from JavaScript if you're running in Node or something.

Comment: can you explain, what does "running in Node" means and how can I do it?

Comment: [Node.js](http://nodejs.org) is a JavaScript environment for server-side programming. It's a completely different environment than a web browser, though the mechanics of using JavaScript are similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript run inside of a client's browser won't actually be able to retrieve another website's html for you (unless it is a different page on your own website).  You may want to read about the [Same-Origin Policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy).

You can, however, use *javascript as a language* to do what you want - just not running inside of a browser.  You can use something called [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/), which is simply a program you can use to run javascript outside of a browser.

What it really boils down to is that if you want to [scrape](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping) another website (which is the term for what you are trying to do), you typically need to make a scraper that runs on a *server*, and not a *browser*.

To be complete, a (probably shady) way to scrape another website is to:

1. Have your server-side code fetch another website's conents
2. Use AJAX to pass the contents to a client's browser
3. Have the client do all of the processing
4. Optionally send the scraped information back to your server

Here is a [good article](http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/scraping-the-web-with-node-js) on scraping with nodeJS.

Answer (score 0):

if you need it just to work on your computer, you can make a userscript that will do this easily. If you want it to work as part of a hosted website, you need a server side solution